# Polymorphic inheritance and merging of interfaces

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

The following class structure:

```
class interface_base
{
    public:
        virtual void f() {};
        virtual void g() {};
};

class interface_base_f : public interface_base
{
    public:
        virtual void f() {};
};

class interface_base_g : public interface_base
{
    public:
        virtual void g() {};
};

class implementation_f1 : public interface_base_f
{
    public:
        virtual void f() { cout << "f1" << endl; };
};

class implementation_f2 : public interface_base_f
{
    public:
        virtual void f() { cout << "f2" << endl; };
};

class implementation_g1 : public interface_base_g
{
    public:
        virtual void g() { cout << "g1" << endl; };
};

class implementation_g2 : public interface_base_g
{
    public:
        virtual void g() { cout << "g2" << endl; };
};
```

So the *interface_base_f* will decide what kind of *f* function use (*f1* or *f2*) and *interface_base_g* will take care about *g*:

```
// Dynamic polymorphism
interface_base_f * ibf = new implementation_f1(); // Not f2!
interface_base_g * ibg = new implementation_g2(); // Not g1!
```

Now I want to do something like this

```
interface_base * ib;
ib = ibf; // now "f" part of "ib" is "ibf" (which is "f1")
ib = ibg; // now "g" part of "ib" is "ibg" (which is "g2") (I hope ...)
ib -> f(); // will get "f1"?
ib -> g(); // will get "g2"?
ib -> f(); // will get "f1"?
```

But **of course**

```
ib = ibf; 
ib = ibg; // overwrites previous instruction!
```

And the output is

```
g2
```

What's the key to make *ib->f()* and *ib->g()* **both** possible? 
Don't forget that *f* and *g* are polymorphic objects (*f* can be *f1 **or** f2* and *g* can be *g1 **or** g2*). Thank you!

Comment: If ou've defined a function virtual in the base class, you don't need to repeat virtual in the derived one.

Comment: @Christophe, isn't it good practice though? Redundant, but explicit, so it's immediately apparent that it's virtual without having to know anything about the parent class.

Comment: @tyler it's true that it's explicit and easy to read. But it can also hide bugs, for example typos or accidental overloads instead of overrides. Personnally i'd prefer making 'override' explicit. But that's a personal opinion.

Comment: @Christohpe, that's a good point. `override` is definitely better.

Answer (score 4):

You can use multiple inheritance combined with [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance):

```
// these need to be redefined virtual
class interface_base_f : public virtual interface_base
{
public:
    virtual void f() {};
};
class interface_base_g : public virtual interface_base
{
public:
    virtual void g() {};
};
```

You can then define a class like:

```
struct implementation_f1g2 : public implementation_f1, public implementation_g2 { };
```

And then apply this construct:

```
implementation_f1g2 *pmy12 = new implementation_f1g2();
pmy12->f(); 
pmy12->g();
interface_base *pb = pmy12;
pb->f();
pb->g();
```

The principle is easy:

- the `virtual` inhertiance means that `interface_base_f` and `interface_base_g` both refer to the same `interface_base`. And this applies also to their derivates.
- the multiple inheritance means that  implementation_f1g2 inherits from the `f()` of `implementation_f1` and from the `g()` of `implementation_g2`.
- Would you just use multiple inheritance, your f1g2 object would inherit of two distinct interface_base subojects, each having its own f() and g() and overridings.  It would hence be ambiguous to call any of these function or to cast to the base class.
- But combining this with the virtual base,  means that despite the multiple inheritance, there is only a single `interface_base` subobject.

[image: Multiple virtual inheritance]